# Is it safe for users of my API to 'Sign In With GitHub' using passport-github?

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth2

I understand that OAuth2 was designed to delegate authorization grants to specific resources, it alone is [not an authentication protocol](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/133065/76844). However, the [`passport-github` README](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-github/blob/master/README.md) states,

> This module lets you *authenticate* using GitHub in your Node.js applications. By plugging into Passport, GitHub authentication can be easily and unobtrusively integrated [...]
>
> The GitHub authentication strategy authenticates users using a GitHub account and OAuth 2.0 tokens.

By using `passport-github` in my HelloAPI, end users would be directed to GitHub's authorization server to start the 3-legged `authorization_code` flow:

- First the user authenticates with GitHub and grants limited access to HelloAPI.
- GitHub redirects the user-agent (browser) back to HelloAPI using a pre-registered `redirect_uri`. The redirection URI includes an authorization code, and optionally, a `state` parameter for cross site request forgery detection.
- HelloAPI quickly exchanges the code for an access token, using the `client_secret` as a means to authenticate HelloAPI with GitHub. (Here too, I should include a `state` parameter.)
- And finally, HelloAPI uses the token to grab whatever GitHub profile is associated with that token.

Here we assume that the token was not created by some other client and subsequently [replayed to HelloAPI as an attack](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/126549/76844) to impersonate a GitHub resource owner. By checking the `state` parameter, I *think* that is a safe assumption, but https://oauth.net/articles/authentication/ warns against doing so:

> OAuth APIs do not provide any mechanism of audience restriction for the returned information. In other words, it is very possible to take a naive client, hand it the (valid) token from another client, and have the naive client treat this as a "log in" event. After all, the token is valid and the call to the API will return valid user information. The problem is of course that the user hasn't done anything to prove that they're present, and in this case they haven't even authorized the naive client.

So this is my hesitation in using `passport-github`: It uses OAuth2 tokens for authentication which is exactly what the experts warn against. Including a `state` parameter seems to secure this server-to-server `authorization_code` flow, but I'm not sure.

What am I missing? Is `passport-github` authentication secure, or is there any way to make a "Sign In With GitHub" feature secure?

Comment: The problem I see is that Step 2 is wrong.  Github does not call the redirect URI, it actuall returns a response to the client with a redirect to the redirect URI.  Also there is no state parameter in step 3.  In step 5:  You create a session token between your client and your HelloAPI.

Comment: (1) Thank you, I fixed the wording. (2) GitHub [accepts](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/) a state parameter for both the `/authorize` and `/access_token` endpoints. (3) I agree. HelloAPI would create a token once the OAuth flow is complete - assuming it is safe to *authenticate* end users with passport-github.

Comment: @Johan, *"You create a session token between your client and your HelloAPI."* Are you implying that an initial, one-time use of the GitHub token is safe for authenticating the end user as long as HelloAPI issues its own token for subsequent requests?

Comment: If done right, yes.  You would not want to re-validate a token against the ID provider on every call!!!! Basically you must apply all the same security measures to this token that you would apply to a session token in any normal Web application.  Use SSL/TLS, For a web based application store it in an HTTP-only cookie with SECURE set on.  For a native application store it safely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that the GitHub OAuth2 implementation supports your use case to authenticate users, so from both a security and maintainability perspective I don't think it is a great idea. From the first paragraph of the [documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/):

> OAuth2 is a protocol that lets external applications request authorization to private details in a user's GitHub account without getting their password.

My assumption in the discussion below is that the authorization code and access token in the GitHub OAuth2 implementation are opaque to your client.

In the GitHub scenario, we have the following OAuth roles:

- Resource Server - GitHub server that provides profile information about users
- Client - Your HelloAPI
- Authorization Server - GitHub auth server
- Resource Owner - Your application end user

The `passport-github` implementation authenticates a user by using the access token gained by your client as part of the OAuth2 flow and then requesting the user profile information from the GitHub resource server at `https://api.github.com/user`.

For example:

1. Joe Bloggs logs in to GitHub via the redirect from your client.
2. The access token that your client receives is opaque containing no information about the identity of Joe.
3. You make a request to the GitHub resource server from your client to retrieve the profile associated with the access token
4. Joe's profile is returned by the resource server and you assume that Joe is the entity that has presented the access token to your client.

The issue for me is that there is no direct 'evidence' as part of this process to ensure that the identity that authenticated to GitHub as part of the OAuth flow is the same identity that is returned in the profile information used to make your authentication decision in the app. For me this is a fail from an information [integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_security#Integrity) perspective, and so I would not consider this 'secure'.

Given that the `passport-github` implementation doesn't appear to be a supported authentication scenario by GitHub it also creates risk in the event that GitHub changes their implementation in any way. It is best to use supported protocols and use APIs for their intended purposes to ensure security and maintainability.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's as safe as any other OAuth login as long as you use security measures via SSL/TLS and as mentioned Github also uses HelloAPI which adds another level of security most other OAuth Login API's do not!
Going by other sites that could be used, after doing some reading, it is as secure as you are going to get with this type of login!